# Dividing and capitalizing words in a string with Java

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a method for an assignment.

Description: If a string contains a word that contains a capital letter, my method needs to capitalize the entire word.

So "hello StackOverFlow, my name is John" would yield "hello STACKOVERFLOW, my name is JOHN"

My code:

```
/*Helper method for capitalizeWords() capitalizes word if necesarry*/
private static String capitalizeWord(String s, int position) {
    int i = position;
    String word = "";
    String testWord = "";

    while (s.charAt(i) != ' ' && i < s.length() - 1) {
        word += s.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
    word += " ";
    testWord = word.toLowerCase();
    if (!testWord.equals(word)) {
        word = word.toUpperCase();
    }
    return word;
}

public static String capitalizeWords(String s) {
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        newString.append(s.charAt(0));
        return newString.toString();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            newString.append(capitalizeWord(s, i));
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            newString.append(capitalizeWord(s, i + 1));
        }
    }
    return newString.toString();
}
```

As you can see my code is inefficient and, when run, skips the last character of the string:

```
HW2.capitalizeWords("Guess what??  There are twenty-sIx letters in the English alphABEt!")  
"GUESS what??  THERE are TWENTY-SIX letters in the ENGLISH ALPHABET "
```

I can't think of a way to fix this without manually adding the last character, which would probably be points off on this assignment. I'd rather learn the right, efficient way to solve this (given the allowed methods) than struggle to come up with a crude solution.

Would any of you mind giving me some ideas? I can't use `substring` or `indexOf`.

Comment: I'd look at using the .split method and provide a space as the argument. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes start with splitting the words of the string either with String.split or a StringTokenizer. Then you can check the first character of each word to decide if you have to capitalize it.

Comment: @hotzst Not necessarily the first, any character.

Comment: @Tunaki right, my oversight

Comment: I would love to use split() but am not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to skipping the last character, check your while loop:

```
while(s.charAt(i) != ' ' && i <s.length()-1)
{
    word += s.charAt(i);
    i++;
}
```

You're looping up until `s.length()-1` but not including it, so you'll be missing off one character. Try using `s.length()` instead. If you want to use `s.length()-1` then you'll need to use `i <= s.length()-1`.

You'll then need to edit your while loop since you'll get an exception when calling `s.charAt(i)` if you leave it like this.

Change your loop to `while(i < s.length() && s.charAt(i))` - the second part won't be evaluated if the first part isn't true, so you'll avoid this error.

Comment: You're going to get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you only do that.

Comment: I was about to add that in when I saw your answer :)

Comment: I've tried this before but receive the following error.java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 67

Comment: As @Makoto says, you need to swap the two halves of your `&&` statement to avoid this error.

Comment: Sorry I just saw Makaot's comment. How can I change the rest of the code to avoid this error?

Comment: It works! I don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks very much! Reps for everyone--scratch that I can't give reps :( but thanks anyways

Comment: Overall, do you guys think this code is acceptable to turn in? How inefficient/sloppy is it exactly? Should I rewrite?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch has given a good solution to the question that's perhaps more efficient than yours. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually pretty close.  There are two changes you need to make.

First, you're iterating over too few characters in your loop.  You want to go all the way to `i < s.length()`, not `s.length() - 1`.

But, if you just make that change, then you'll have a problem with `s.charAt(i)` statement since `i` will be out of bounds on the next loop.

To get around *that*, flip your `&&`:

```
while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) != ' ') {
    word += s.charAt(i);
    i++;
}
```

Since `&&` short-circuits, you won't evaluate the second part of it if `i >= s.length()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code and take advantage of the utility methods in `Character` (such as [`isWhitespace(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) and [`isUpperCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29)). I would also suggest using a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Then you might build an individual word in place. Something like,

```
public static String capitalizeWords(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    boolean capital = false;
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
            if (word.length() > 0) {
                sb.append(capital ? word.toString().toUpperCase() : word);
                word.setLength(0);
                capital = false;
            }
            sb.append(ch);
            continue;
        } else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            capital = true;
        }
        word.append(ch);
    }
    if (word.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(capital ? word.toString().toUpperCase() : word);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

which I tested with

```
System.out.println(capitalizeWords("Guess what??  There are twenty-sIx letters "
    + "in the English alphABEt!"));
System.out.println(capitalizeWords("hello StackOverFlow, my name is John"));
```

Getting (the expected)

```
GUESS what??  THERE are TWENTY-SIX letters in the ENGLISH ALPHABET!
hello STACKOVERFLOW, my name is JOHN
```

Comment: I really appreciate the solution. Unfortunately, we are not allowed to use "continue" in our loops. Additionally, we are not allowed to use arrays. My professor seems to think that it is used to compensate for a poorly designed loop, but I have used it personally in my code and never had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following code can help you with your task.

```
public String capitalize(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
        String word = words[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); ++j) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(j))) {
                words[i] = words[i].toUpperCase();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (String word : words) {
        result.append(word).append(" ");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```